# Multie Workers on a list of items

Tags: python, multithreading

I am attempting to generate multiple threads, each calling a function that processes an item from a list. Illustration below, however I am getting the following error and im not entirely sure why `TypeError: stuff() takes exactly 1 argument (56 given)`. The below code is a snippet to test the functionality of the idea. I will be checking each thread is still active before continuing (this will be later once the cause of the error is IDed). Any help would be appreicated. I believe the thread takes arguments as a list, and this could be the cause (the filename is being split) but im not sure how to takle list (one for each item in the list) problem. If you cant parse the item to the function.

```
def stuff(filename):
    Stuff done to filename


threads = []
for filename in file_list: #File list contains list of full path filenames.
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=stuff, args=(filename))
    threads.append(thread1)
    thread1.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass a tuple to `args`. Without a comma `,`, it is not a tuple -- it is just a simple expression that is parenthesized.

```
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=stuff, args=(filename,))
                                                       ^^^
```